# Form three squares of equal area with 8 sticks

Tags: geometry

This puzzle comes from a Chinese puzzle book. This is the translation of the puzzle:

> There are 4 sticks 10 cm long and 4 sticks 5 cm long. How to form three squares of equal area with these sticks?

Despite trying my best, I could not figure this out. Any help in this problem is appreciated. Thank you.

Source: 450 multiple intelligence games that Harvard made for students puzzle book(translated, original title(in Chinese): 哈佛给学生做的450个多元智能顺练游戏)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three (only three) squares of equal area:

> [image]

Comment: Really the question should have been a lot clearer.

Answer (score 2):

May be it looks a bit dirty, but who said it shouldn't...?

> [image]